# Scraping URLs and Descriptions from HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, url, apify

I'm quite new to coding and i'm struggling with returning multiple URLs and Descriptions from a block of HTML code. I know i have to loop it somehow but don't know how. Hope someone can help me please. What i have is

```js
function pageFunction(context) {
 
    const $ = context.jQuery;
    const venueName = $('div.collist a').first().text() + ' /';
    const venueURL = $('div.collist a[href]').attr('href');


    return {
        venueName,
        venueURL
    };
}
```

The HTML code i'm trying to scrape is

```html
    </div>
    <div class="collist">
    <h3>Properties</h3>x
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
    <a href="search?query=500" rel="nofollow" title="Venue1"><span>London, UK</span></a> (<span>810</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=600" rel="nofollow" title="Venue2"><span>Pretoria, South Africa</span></a> (<span>820</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=700" rel="nofollow" title="Venue3"><span>New York, USA</span></a> (<span>830</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=800" rel="nofollow" title="Venue4"><span>Paris, France</span></a> (<span>840</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=900" rel="nofollow" title="Venue5"><span>Denver, USA</span></a> (<span>850</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=1000" rel="nofollow" title="Venue6"><span>Deli, India</span></a> (<span>860</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=1100" rel="nofollow" title="Venue7"><span>Lisbon, Protugal</span></a> (<span>870</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=1200" rel="nofollow" title="Venue8"><span>Madrid, Spain/span></a> (<span>880</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=1300" rel="nofollow" title="Venue9><span>Berlin, Germany</span></a> (<span>890</span>)
    </li><li>
    <a href="search?query=1400" rel="nofollow" title="Venue10"><span>Stockholm, Sweden</span></a> (<span>900</span>)
    </li>
    </ul>
```

My current results are

```json
    [{
      "venueName": "London, UK /",
      "venueURL": "search?query=500"
    }]
```

But what i would like to see

```json
    [{
      "venueName": "London, UK /","venueURL": "search?query=500",
    },{
      "venueName": "Pretoria, South Africa /","venueURL": "search?query=600",
    },{
      "venueName": "New York, USA /","venueURL": "search?query=700",
    },{
      "venueName": "Paris, France /","venueURL": "search?query=800",
    },{
      "venueName": "Denver, USA / ","venueURL": "search?query=900",
    }]
```

I have tried to put in .each()

```js
function pageFunction(context) {
    
    const $ = context.jQuery;
     const venueURL = $('div.collist a[href]').each(function(index, value){console.log(this.href);})
    
    
    return {
        venueURL
    };
}
```

and when i run it in the browser console is seems to work, but as soon as i run it in the app i get the following error

> ERROR PuppeteerCrawler: handleRequestFunction failed, reclaiming
> failed request back to the list or queue
>
> Error: Evaluation failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: your code is somewhat working. You only have accessed the first element. This is how jQuery works. Just turn it into a loop-based flow to access all `<a>` elements you've retrieved. jQuery has an useful function for this: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) Once you have added this, you will get the desired output. You're almost there!

Comment: Awesome thank you let me give it a bash

Comment: Is your desired output example correct? You have duplicated keys, London appearing twice, and missing commas. If converted to an object, I'm not sure it would contain more than the last entry for two keys.

Comment: tried adding a each() looks fine in then console but as soon as i run it in the app, i get errors

Comment: `const venueURL = $(...).each()` makes little sense to begin with, `each` does not _return_ anything.

Comment: I'm completely lost as how to make the each() work

Answer (score 0):

When you try to return a non-stringifiable object from the page function, you get that error. Means that trying to get `each()` to the dataset is not possible, since it's a jQuery object and `JSON.stringify` fails. You need to return an array of objects for each one of your results to become a separate dataset item like this:

```js
function pageFunction(context) {
 
    const $ = context.jQuery;
    const results = [];
    
    // treat the parent as the unique container of data
    $('.collist li').each((_, li) => {
      const $li = $(li);
      // find the data individually per found LI element 
      const $link = $li.find('a').first();
      // using text() on an element that have children can include a lot of whitespace, narrow down to `span`
      const venueName = $link.find('span').first().text() + ' /';
      const venueURL = $link.attr('href');

      results.push({
        venueName,
        venueURL
      });
    });

    return results;
}
```